# Analysis, implicit functions

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Let $X=(x_0,y_0)=(1,1) \in \mathcal{R}^2$. Prove that there exists $\rho>0$ and continuously differentiable functions $u,v,w: B_{\rho}(X) \to \mathcal{R} $ such that

$u(X) = 1, v(X) = 1, w(X) = -1$

and

$u^5(x,y) + xv^2(x,y)-y+w(x,y) = 0$

$v^5(x,y)+yu^2(x,y)-x+w(x,y)=0$

$w^4(x,y)+y^5-x^4=1$

Can you give me any hint to solving this or how to approach this? I think it has something to do with implicit functions but I am not sure. 
Thank you.